# How to access the values of HTTP Response object in java

Tags: java, json, http, httpresponse

I'm sending a request to a server and getting the response to a Response object. It outputs a Json object in postman. I need to know the way to access the values in it. Here's my code.

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
    }

    if(response.code() == 200) {
        //need to access the response object
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output at postman for the same request

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Udana"
    },
]
```

When I try it this way 
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

it gives the following error

W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Response of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Can you specify library are you using? It looks like _Retrofit_. Am I right?

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to make a android app with java

Answer (score 0):

You could specify `Call` and `Response` type. E.g., `Call<List<IdNameType>>`, where `IdNameType` is the a bean which represents your JSON objects.

A draft below:

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<IdNameType>> call, Response<List<IdNameType>> response) throws IOException {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
    }

    if(response.code() == 200) {
            List<IdNameType> responseContent = response.body();
            // Use response
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can manually manage the response content getting the raw OkHttp response with `Response::raw`.